# How to connect page numbers in bibliography with ~ instead of -- (en dash)?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

It is one of my school's rule to use '~' instead of '--' to combine page numebers in the bibiograhy citation list. I tried to modify the original .bst style file, but I am new to biblatex's grammer. I figured out that the critical codes that define the page numbers default behavior look like this:

```
   FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{ 't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
    { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
        { "--" *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
        {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
        { "-" *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
          while$
        }
      if$
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ *
      t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
    }
      if$
    }
  while$
}
```

With these codes, the original compiled latex file looks like this:
[image: original effect]

But I want the page numbers to be connected by the "~" symbol instead of '--', like this:
[image: wanted effect]
I would very appreciate it if anybody can offer some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
FUNCTION { n.dashify }
{
  't :=
  ""
    { t empty.or.unknown not }
    {
      t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
        {
          t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
            { "\textasciitilde{}" *
              t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
            }
            {
              { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
              {
                t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
              }
              while$
              "\textasciitilde{}" t * 't :=
            }
          if$
        }
        {
          t #1 #1 substring$ *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}
```

The unnamed `bst` language uses the reverse Polish notation, so it is not easy to understand the logic of the the program.  Basically if we see a lone `-`, we substitute it for `\textasciitilde{}`, and if we see a string of `-`, we delete them and put `\textasciitilde{}` instead.

Comment: Finally got the problem solved by adopting to your code! Truely appreciate your help, sir!

Answer (score 0):

## Do a global search and replace in the `.bib` file ?

I think an easier way is to avoid changing any `.bst` style files and just do a global search and replace in any `.bib` files you have. While this is easier I don't think it is a great idea in case there are any `---` (em dash) in there, so do any replacement with care. (Also I am unsure if this will line-break nicely, and doubt it).

[image]

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{author00,
title = {{A Title}},
author= {Person, Some},
journal={SIAM Journal on Something},
volume={10},
number={1},
pages={25\textasciitilde2587},
year={2011},
publisher={SIAM}
}

@article{author01,
title = {{A Title}},
author= {Person, Some},
journal={SIAM Journal on Something},
volume={10},
number={1},
pages={25$\sim$2587},
year={2011},
publisher={SIAM}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{extarticle}
\usepackage[numbers, sort&compress]{natbib} % Nice references.
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{author00} and \citet{author01}.
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```